# OneDrive API: get pictures taken on Monday

Tags: onedrive

Is it possible to retrieve pictures taken on Monday?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. OData Version 4.0 offers no function for checking the day the week. See list of [Built-in Query Functions](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Built-in_Query_Functions). And even if it did, OneDrive doesn't support built-in query functions. See [Filtering a collection](https://dev.onedrive.com/odata/filtering.htm) in OneDrive API documentation.